# SQL logic error or missing database for Blackberry

Tags: sql, sqlite, blackberry, java-me

I'm fairly new with SQLite for Blackberry, and i'm testing my program, tryign to implement SQLite, but i don see the problem on this query

```
CREATE TABLE 'LECGRAL'('ID_LEC' TEXT  NOT NULL,
'ID_LECTURISTA'    TEXT,
'COD_UNICOM'       TEXT  NOT NULL,
'RUTA'             TEXT  NOT NULL,
'ITINERARIO'       TEXT  NOT NULL,
'CICLO'            TEXT  NOT NULL,
'ESTADO'           TEXT  NOT NULL,)
```

SQL logic error or missing database is the erro i'm getting. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

I think the trailing comma:

```
'ESTADO'           TEXT  NOT NULL,)
                                 ^ Right here
```

is the source of your trouble. As an aside, you don't need to quote those column or table names, this:

```
CREATE TABLE LECGRAL(
    ID_LEC           TEXT  NOT NULL,
    ID_LECTURISTA    TEXT,
    COD_UNICOM       TEXT  NOT NULL,
    RUTA             TEXT  NOT NULL,
    ITINERARIO       TEXT  NOT NULL,
    CICLO            TEXT  NOT NULL,
    ESTADO           TEXT  NOT NULL
)
```

should be okay.